# tableHeaderView tableFooterView

Tags: iphone

i want to create a table view with contacts as in native contacts app of iPhone i have an array of name and i want to show the tableHeaderView and tableFooterView like the native contacts screen of iPhone for eg a b c how can we do it in our app

Answer (score 1):

This answers are not ok as they refer to section header/footer views. You should implement tableView.tableHeaderView.